# which() function for lists in R

Tags: r, text-mining

This should be easy, but I am hoping to find out how to return the indices of a list that contain one element. For example, in the list below, let's say I want to find all indices where "a" is an element. I would want a function to return the index 1.

```
> x = list(c("a", "b"), "c")

> x
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

[[2]]
[1] "c"

> which(x=="a")

integer(0)
```

Of course, which() does not work here. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

You need to iterate over the list elements and check for the element in each set.  The

```
sapply(x, function(e) is.element('a', e))
## [1]  TRUE FALSE
which(sapply(x, function(e) is.element('a', e)))
## [1] 1
```

The `sapply` expression returns a logical vector, indicating the presence of `a` each element of the list, and `which` returns the indices of the `TRUE` elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear to me how you want result formatted.  Since there are two list elements, it would be difficult to determine which list element the match came from when you have a longer list, should you simply want the indices as a vector. You could use `which` here. Just write

`sapply(x, function(y) which(y == "a"))`

Or you could use `grep`, which returns the index of the matched pattern. Here I'll show it used on the unlisted list, and then iterated over the list.

```
> grep("a", unlist(x))
# [1] 1
> sapply(x, function(y) grep("a", y))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1

# [[2]]
# integer(0)
```

You could also use `%in%` to see exactly where the occurrences of `"a"` are. This returns a logical vector.

```
> lapply(x, `%in%`, "a")   ## or lapply(x, `==`, "a")
# [[1]]
# [1]  TRUE FALSE

# [[2]]
# [1] FALSE
```